# Android Tablet 10.1 only - Parent activity not maintaining state

Tags: android

Application contains 3 Activity's 
1) HomeScreen - Contains 8 Fragments.
2) VideoActivity 
3) Another Activity

Steps When i launch any activity from fragments of 1st activity and then again come back to 1st activity by pressing back button from Activity 2 or Activity 3. Activitys current state get destroyed and it starts from first fragments. 
This issue is coming only on 10.1" Tablets not on any other devices.
Strange !!

Thanks for the Help in Advance 
Kishor